# Duplicate Button actions on different View Controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a button on one of my view controllers which controls a score action (counter).

Can someone help me duplicating the button and the action it takes and place the duplicate on a separate ViewController?

I need this for a workout Application i'm making and I want to get the action Proof of concept complete before I implement it into my App.

I have attached my Xcode Project with the stage I am now on.

Ive tried passing the name of the action button from the main VC to the newest but I've had no luck.

https://github.com/Mulreany93/NewVCActionButton

Answer (score 1):

I saw in your GitHub that you have an empty class called ViewControllerNewButton, which inherits from UIViewController. I suggest making your scorebutton into a new class called something like e.g. ScoreButton, which should inherit directly from UIButton - `class ScoreButton: UIButton {...}` Then in each View Controller you can create your scorebutton: `let scoreButtonTest = ScoreButton()` and then you can use e.g. conversion functions like `scoreButtonTest.someConversion()` from your ScoreButton class.

If I am on the wrong track, feel free to comment but as far as I can tell you are just trying to use your button in multiple VCs and that's a good place to try inheritance.

Edit for clarification:

```
 class ScoreButton: UIButton {
  func someConversion() {
   ...
  }
 }
```

Comment: Would I create the new class of `Score Button` and then put the counter action inside it to call?

Comment: @JoeMulreany yes you create the new class and inside it you create `func someConversion() {...}`

Comment: When I create `class Scorebutton: UIButton{
    }`

It doesnt let me input my action in my code `@IBAction func counter(sender: AnyObject) {
        scorestart += 1
        scorelbl.text = NSString(format: "%i", scorestart) as String` inside the class

Comment: @JoeMulreany remove the `@IBAction` - check my edited answer

Comment: When I input the code into the class it now shows this error https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzyBGA-ffMYLTjRkWEJhc2U4RWc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @JoeMulreany your class ScoreButton should be in a separate file called ScoreButton.swift. Go to File -> New -> File -> Cocoa Touch Class and in Class enter ScoreButton and in Subclass enter UIButton

Comment: Now I have done that and put the function inside the Swift file it states use of unresolved identifier being scorelbl and score start. because those items are in the original  View Controller, Would you be able to edit my github file so I can see exactly what has been done?

Comment: @JoeMulreany scorelbl is an IBOutlet from your Storyboard and it can't be a part of your new class. You can only use your new class to perform calculations etc. and return your values to your ViewController. Changes to your Storyboard's items can only be performed in your ViewController. So changing the label's text should remain in each ViewController if you are using the Storyboard.

Comment: I understand that.. so what function do I put in the Scorebutton.swift file because without the IBOutlets the function wont work to use in the View Controllers :( and then how do I call it from the button press

Comment: @JoeMulreany I assumed that you want to do further calculations etc. and the GitHub code was just the beginning. If you **just** want to manipulate your Storyboard (your IBOutlets) with the function, you have to do so for each controller manually. The only alternative is to have your UILabels in a separate class as well and then you add those to your View programmatically but given that you are just starting out, I'd advise you against that option.

Comment: I didn't want to manipulate further, this is for a fitness tracking app Im making, i had the function working just as i wanted, I just wanted to have the function from the button working on more than View controller, I wanted the scorebutton function to take place from 2 view controllers. I thank you for your help but i think it has been over complicated

Comment: @JoeMulreany You are welcome! In that case continue working as before and when you need to do more stuff use inheritance as I showed you to save time.

Comment: The Inheritance isnt making sense to me, would you be able to edit the file in the github repository so i can take a look (sorry its how my mind works with some things)